# Clang++ shipped with Visual Studio 2019: lld-link reports undefined symbol __guard_eh_cont_table

Tags: c++, windows, linker, clang++

To build a basic C++ code:

## Code

```
//test.cpp
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Build command (in PowerShell using):

## VS 2019

### Option 1 (Successful)

```
clang++ -o test.exe .\test.cpp -fuse-ld=link -v
```

### Option 2 (Fail)

```
clang++ -o test.exe .\test.cpp -fuse-ld=lld-link -v
```

## VS 2022

Both option 1 and 2 are successful.

## Platform

OS: Win 10 (64-bit)

SDK: 18362

VS: 2019/2022

Compiler: clang++ (12.0.0) in the VS 2019 and clang++ (15.0.0) in the VS 2022

## Log for VS 2019, option 2

```
clang version 12.0.0
Target: x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: D:\VS2019\VC\Tools\Llvm\x64\bin
 "D:\\VS2019\\VC\\Tools\\Llvm\\x64\\bin\\clang++.exe" -cc1 -triple x86_64-pc-windows-msvc19.35.32217 -emit-obj -mrelax-all -mincremental-linker-compatible --mrelax-relocations -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name test.cpp -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mframe-pointer=none -fmath-errno -fno-rounding-math -mconstructor-aliases -munwind-tables -target-cpu x86-64 -tune-cpu generic -v -resource-dir "D:\\VS2019\\VC\\Tools\\Llvm\\x64\\lib\\clang\\12.0.0" -internal-isystem "D:\\VS2019\\VC\\Tools\\Llvm\\x64\\lib\\clang\\12.0.0\\include" -internal-isystem "D:\\VS2022\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.35.32215\\include" -internal-isystem "D:\\VS2022\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.35.32215\\atlmfc\\include" -internal-isystem "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\Include\\10.0.18362.0\\ucrt" -internal-isystem "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\include\\10.0.18362.0\\shared" -internal-isystem "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\include\\10.0.18362.0\\um" -internal-isystem "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\include\\10.0.18362.0\\winrt" -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir "D:\\build" -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length=120 -fno-use-cxa-atexit -fms-extensions -fms-compatibility -fms-compatibility-version=19.35.32217 -std=c++14 -fdelayed-template-parsing -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fcolor-diagnostics -faddrsig -o "C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\test-60912f.o" -x c++ ".\\test.cpp"
clang -cc1 version 12.0.0 based upon LLVM 12.0.0 default target x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 D:\VS2019\VC\Tools\Llvm\x64\lib\clang\12.0.0\include
 D:\VS2022\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\include
 D:\VS2022\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\atlmfc\include
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt
End of search list.
 "D:\\VS2019\\VC\\Tools\\Llvm\\x64\\bin\\lld-link" -out:test.exe -defaultlib:libcmt -defaultlib:oldnames "-libpath:D:\\VS2022\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.35.32215\\lib\\x64" "-libpath:D:\\VS2022\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.35.32215\\atlmfc\\lib\\x64" "-libpath:C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\Lib\\10.0.18362.0\\ucrt\\x64" "-libpath:C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\Lib\\10.0.18362.0\\um\\x64" "-libpath:D:\\VS2019\\VC\\Tools\\Llvm\\x64\\lib\\clang\\12.0.0\\lib\\windows" -nologo "C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\test-60912f.o"

lld-link: error: undefined symbol: __guard_eh_cont_table
>>> referenced by libcmt.lib(loadcfg.obj):(_load_config_used)

lld-link: error: undefined symbol: __guard_eh_cont_count
>>> referenced by libcmt.lib(loadcfg.obj):(_load_config_used)
```

Clang++ shipped with VS 2019 fails to build a simple program when the linker is specified with  **lld-link**. But **Link** can make it.

No problem for the VS 2022, whatever lld-link or link.

### Test

1. No problem for both options (1 and 2) on **another PC** with only VS 2019 installed.
2. PC with dual-VS (19 and 22) reports the error for VS 2019.

Google shows that the symbol of **__guard_eh_cont_table** relates to the exception handler.

So I tried to change the SDK with three versions (from 18*** to 20***) to see if SDK may influence the exception method, but the problem remains.

Also, I reinstalled the clang++ in VS2019, which does not work.

I suspect the VS 2022 breaks some components of VS 2019, like the search path of the DLL/LIB.

Would you mind giving some suggestions about the compatibility between different versions of VS?

Thank you for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the env varible name "VCToolsInstallDir" and the value "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133". Worked for me after VS2022 install. Please make sure the value path exists!
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But then the new problem is that I cannot find a directory like **BuildTools**. Maybe I don't install additional build tools except for the MSVC and Clang compilers. Also, there is another Tool in the **\Visual Studio\2019\VC\Tools. Please correct me, if I do misunderstand the difference between the BuildTools\VC\Tools and the 2019\VC\Tools.

Comment: you can install the build tools with this executable https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/vs_buildtools.exe